# HLS to MPEG DASH

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

Im currently working on a platform that relies on MPEG Dash to deliver audio and video to the browser.
For onDemand im using ffmpeg to encode videos to h264/aac and MP4Box to create the manifest.mpd file.
Now im trying to figure out how to create live MPEG Dash streams, more specifically encode hls live streams to MPEG Dash.

1. Do i need to reencode all the .ts segments to .mp4(h264/aac) segments, since chrome doesnt support mpeg2ts?
2. If so, how do i continuously reencode all the segments (different resolution, different bitrates)
3. How do i create a dynamic manifest with MP4Box / how would the input parameter look like

Comment: maybe you should take a look at the hasplayer.js https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/hasplayer.js/tree/master It transforms HLS and Smooth Streaming content to DASH. As far as i know they got JS functions to do the manifest/segment mapping/rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the representations/renditions of the HLS stream, you basically would just need to remultiplex the mpeg2ts segments into IBMFF/MP4 segments + create the DASH init file. There are streaming servers like wowza or Unified Streaming which can do that afaik.

Comment: i dont want to use a 3rd party service to create the files and the manifest. can i create the IBMFF/MP4 segments by using ffmpeg and the -c:v copy argument?

Comment: I don't think you can do all of HLS to a playable DASH conversion in ffmpeg. The fragments, maybe yes you can convert an mpeg2-ts to ISOBMFF, but there's more to that if you want to have a playable DASH content, like building the segment initialization file and a corresponding manifest for the converted fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on MPEG DASH for both onDemand and Live profiles. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and this is what I do. I use avconv to convert an input chunk from mp2t to mp4 then ffmpeg to chunk the video and align the I-frames and then I use MP4Box to create the .mpd and the segments. For live streaming I use ffmpeg to record a clip using my webcam, convert the mpeg2 to mpeg4 format and then finally use MP4Box to produce dynamic segments. Now, for your questions:

1. You should convert the input stream from mpeg2 to mpeg4 before segmenting them to save converting the segments later,
2. To continuously encode onDemand content: this is not really required since the content is converted in one shot, but should you still require that, you could write a simple bash script to loop the avconv and ffmpeg command in series,
3. To produce dynamic content your command should look something like this:

---

```
MP4Box -dash-live DUR(in ms) -fps 24 -some_other_params_you_want_to_use -dash-ctx filename -dynamic -out filename
```

---

Happy to provide more info!
Cheers